# How to access indexed id in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, indexing

I am having trouble in accessing an element to validate it.

For example, if I am generating a dynamic table from a database and I have a code that looks something like this:

```
i=0;

while($row as values){

    <input type='text' id='quantity[$i]' name='quantity[$i]' value=''>
    <input type='text' id='quantity_req[$i]' name='quantity_req[$i]' value=''>

    $i++;
}
<input type='hidden' id='i' name='i' value='$i'>
```

I can use `$('#i').val()` to get the value of i, but how can I get the values of the text fields?

`$('#quantity[i]').val();` and `$('#quantity[i]').val();` doesn't work, javascript seem to think of "#quantity[i]" as a string, even though I have given 'i' a value through a for loop.

I also tried `$('#quantity' +i).val()` but it's not working too.

Comment: Its simple bro, to get the value of a text field, you need to extract the textfield by classname/id. eg:-`$('#txt').val();` where #txt is the id of the text field.

Comment: Actually the string is a good example of why string interpolation would not work well in JS (at least without any special syntax or format). You said *"even though I have given 'i' a value through a for loop"*. So you expect `'[i]'` to be replaced with something like `'[0]'`. But how can JavaScript know that it should not replace the `i` in `quantity`? If JS would replace variables, the resulting string would be `'#quant0ty[0]'`.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): *"To use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: ``\\``."*

Comment: I somehow expected the brackets to help in classifying it as a variable.

Comment: @dreamweiver That's exactly what the OP is trying ...

Comment: Yeah well... as already said, JavaScript does not do string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var ival=$('#i').val();
$('#quantity\\[' +ival+'\\]').val()
```

Comment: `[` and `]` are special characters in jQuery selectors that need to be escaped

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Ian. This really helped.

Answer (score 1):

> javascript seem to think of "#quantity[i]" as a string

That's right. `"#quantity[i]"` **is** a string; Javascript doesn't look at parts of a string that happen to name variables.

You need to *concatenate* the value into your string, as you tries at the end.
However, you also need to concatenate in the brackets; you concatenated `#quantity1`, which isn't the string you're looking for.

You also need to escape the brackets, or jQuery will parse them as an attribute selector.

Comment: If that's the case then this should work ->$('#quantity[' +i+']').val() but it still doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing javascript variables and PHP variables.

PHP variables are with the '$' before the name of the variable.

If you want to get the value of the inputs you have to use the PHP variable, no te letter 'i' like you are using.

You have to do like answer from rahul maindargi and it should works.